# System.loadLibrary in android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I made this in a simple java program

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

    String cascade= "img/test.xml";
    String imgloc= "img/asd.png";

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(cascade);
    Mat image = Highgui.imread(imgloc);

    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    }

    String filename = "ouput.jpg";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
    Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
```

It detects faces from an image and outputs the detected faces. Now I want to include it into an android project, but `System.loadLibrary` is making my app. crash. How can I solve this?

Here's the crashlog

```
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): Process: com.tppa.detector, PID: 1564
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.opencv.core.Core
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.tppa.detector.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-11 10:44:23.296: E/AndroidRuntime(1564):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-11 10:44:23.304: W/ActivityManager(479):   Force finishing activity com.tppa.detector/.MainActivity
01-11 10:44:23.452: D/dalvikvm(479): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 543K, 23% free 6457K/8320K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
01-11 10:44:23.956: W/ActivityManager(479): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{528f2d70 u0 com.tppa.detector/.MainActivity t8 f}
01-11 10:44:24.004: W/EGL_genymotion(655): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-11 10:44:33.080: E/WindowManager(479): Starting window AppWindowToken{529d5a4c token=Token{528e29fc ActivityRecord{528f2d70 u0 com.tppa.detector/.MainActivity t8}}} timed out
```

It worked in simple Java, I added the .jar to a new library in build path, and as the native library I added the .dll, but it seems for android it won't work.

Comment: Did you build the native portion using the NDK? https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Tools

Comment: I never posted crashlog, did I do it right? I also don't understand what native means.

Comment: `System.loadLibrary()` is not making your app crash.  The inability to find `org.opencv.core.Core` is.  Is there an earlier failure that you're not showing in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in your comments, you have to compile your library for android architecture. DLL files are for Windows. That's why your compiler can't find any symbol.

[Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) allows you to compile static (.a) or shared (.so) library for different architecture such as armeabi, armeabi-v7a or x86, depending on your needs.